# Xpages repeat control get id of inputText

Tags: input, xpages, repeat, xpages-ssjs

I have an xpages where I have a repeat control and I added a button to increment the number of repeats.
Within the repeat I have an inputText and a ComputedField. I want to get the ID of each inputText and do something with it, maybe add them. I added an index to the repeat and the label of my inputText is: input$(index). I want to access with getComponent("input"+index) but it says: getComponent is null. Why?

What is the inputText id?

P.S. This is the code:

```
<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.dynaField=parseInt("1")}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>

    <xp:div style="text-align:center">
        <xp:inputText id="number" defaultValue="100">
            <xp:this.converter>
                <xp:convertNumber type="number" integerOnly="true"></xp:convertNumber>
            </xp:this.converter>
        </xp:inputText></xp:div>
    <xp:panel id="Panel_All" style="text-align:center">


        <xp:repeat id="repeat1" var="testCollection" indexVar="index"
            value="#{javascript:parseInt(sessionScope.dynaField)}" rows="120"
            style="border:1pt" repeatControls="false" first="0">
            <xp:inputText id="input${index}">

                <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="repeat1">
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:inputText>


            <xp:text escape="true" id="comp">

                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var repeatValue = getComponent("repeat1").getValue();
var number1 = getComponent("number").getValue();
var number2 = getComponent("input").getValue();

return number1-number2;
}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>

            <xp:br></xp:br></xp:repeat>



        <xp:br></xp:br>


        <xp:br></xp:br>
        <xp:table style="width:100%">

            <xp:tr>
                <xp:td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
                    <xp:button value="Add Document" id="button1">
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="Panel_All">
                            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.dynaField=parseInt(sessionScope.dynaField)+1
getComponent("repeat1").setValue(parseInt(sessionScope.dynaField));}]]></xp:this.action>
                        </xp:eventHandler>
                    </xp:button>

                </xp:td>

            </xp:tr>
        </xp:table>
        </xp:panel>
```

I have the first inputText with the id number, where is the initial number. Then the repeat have an input text and a computed field that shows the difference between the "number", first inputText and the inputText in the repeat.
Then if the user clicks the button a new inputText shows in the repeat and the computed field related to that field the result should be: (number)-1st inputText in the repeat - 2nd inputText in the field.

Thanks,

Florin

Comment: Could you tell us what the business need is, rather than the technical approach? I see the technical approach in your comment on David's answer, but I don't understand why you're adding and subtracting.

Comment: Oh, and could we see the actual code?

Comment: Could we go back to the first question - what is the business need you're trying to address? Having some input fields that show the variation of the input's value from 100 seems very theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's the best approach.  I never pull data from the repeat control itself like that.  I'd sooner just go back to disk and calculate it that way.

Assuming you want these totals outside the repeat control I'd have a SSJS or Java function to get the totals and just present it that way. Actually you could do this in the repeat control itself really.  You could use the domino object model to collect your documents...  do any calculations you want at the that time and store the results in viewScope and then return to the repeat control a viewEntryCollection of your selected documents...

Comment: I want to use the repeat to add values in the inputText, and then in the same repeat I have a computedField where I want to substract the value of each input field. For example I have a number 1000 when I add an inputText with a value of 200 the result will be 800, then when I add another input with 100 value, the 2nd computed field to have the value of 700, and so on.